# Mistake in evaluating this limit

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

$$f(x)= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \frac{n^n(x+n)(x+n/2)...(x+n/n)}{n! (x^2+n^2)(x^2+n^2/4)...(x^2+n^2/n^2)} \right] ^{x/n}$$

Find the function f.

The way I evaluated the limit is by taking out a common factor of $n$ or $n^2$ from each bracket.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \frac{n^{2n}(\frac{x}{n}+1)(\frac{x}{n}+1/2)...(\frac{x}{n}+1/n)}{n!*n^{2n} (\frac{x^2}{n^2}+1)(\frac{x^2}{n^2} +1/4)...(\frac{x^2}{n^2} +1/n^2)} \right] ^{x/n}$$

But $x/n \to 0$ so this simplifies to
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\frac{1/2*1/3....*1/n}{n! * 1/4 * 1/9 * ... *1/n^2}\right]^{x/n}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 1^{x/n} = 1^0 = 1$$

But this is wrong. I want to know where the mistake is, a rigorous/formal way to point out of my mistake.

Note: I do not want the solution.

Comment: You cannot let a few instances of $n\to\infty$ while leaving the others alone. Doing so leads to wacky results. For instance, let $a_n=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$. Of course $a_n\to e$, but if you do what you did here, you'd be arguing $\lim a_n=\lim1^n=1$.

Comment: @NoChance yes that is the same question but as i said i don't want a solution, just wanted to know my mistake.

Comment: @user170231 hmm thanks that makes sense but I'm also still wondering if i were to rigorously do this, what would my mistake be in this simplification?

Comment: You could consider rewriting the exponential in the form$$a^b=e^{b\ln(a)},$$
expand the log-of-product into a sum-of-logs, then try to relate the sum to a definite integral. (This is exactly what the linked answer is showing, with the exception of the vanishing factors of $n^n$ and $n^{2n}$.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the final step? It is clear that the $n!$ will cancel out, then what?

Comment: @NoChance the n! cancels out and 1 is left inside the bracket. Which is what I wrote.

Comment: But you would be left out with: $(\frac{1}{1/4 * 1/9 * ... *1/n^2})^{x/n}$

Comment: @NoChance No. 1/n! In the numerator does not cancel with n! In the denominator.